# get all jenkins jobs build periodically with groovy scripts

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I need help with a groovy script to get all jobs in Jenkins that run periodically then enable discard old builds something like 30 days rotation.

Thank

Comment: What have you got so far? A quick google search or search of S/O will give answers to both problems.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something that might be useful for others, hope someone can validate :)

```js
def daysToKeep = 30
def numToKeep = -1
def artifactDaysToKeep = -1
def artifactNumToKeep = -1
jenkins = Hudson.instance
def count=0
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.triggers.*
for(item in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.Job.class))
{  
  def timerTrigger = item.triggers.get(Jenkins.instance.getDescriptor(hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger.class));
  def className = item.getClass();
  def buildDiscarder = item.getBuildDiscarder()
  if (item.class.canonicalName == "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject") {
  if( buildDiscarder != null && item.disabled==false && timerTrigger) {
  count+=1
  if (timerTrigger) {
      schedule=timerTrigger.spec
  }
  def lastBuild = item.getLastBuild()? item.getLastBuild().number: "Never built once";
  def lastBuildOnDate = item.getLastBuild()? item.getLastBuild().getTime():"Never built once"
  def url = item.getUrl()
  def schedule=''
  println("=====================")
  println "$count, $item.fullName, disabled=$item.disabled, Last Build On:$lastBuildOnDate"
  println("JOB: " + item.name)
  println jenkins.getRootUrl()+item.getUrl()+'configure'
  item.buildDiscarder = new hudson.tasks.LogRotator(daysToKeep,numToKeep, artifactDaysToKeep, artifactNumToKeep)
  item.save()
  println("")
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this porpose you can sheck 'Configuration slicing plugin' which will help you in setting the same parameters for multiple jobs.